# Spring Security (3.2.5) HTTP POST not forwarding to the original request after authentication

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc, post, spring-security

I have a sample Spring MVC application, secured by Spring security (Spring version 4.0.1.RELEASE, Spring security 3.2.5.RELEASE.  When I send an HTTP GET request as an unauthenticated user, I am sent to the login page (as expected) where after I authenticate I am sent along to the page that was requested in the original GET.

When I send an HTTP POST request as an unauthenticated user, I am sent to the login page (as expected), but then after successful authentication I am sent to the page as specified in my "default-target-url" instead of the page as requested in my original POST request.

When I try this same HTTP POST as an authenticated user, it works just fine (as expected).  I have already tried setting always-use-default-target="false" as well as omitting that property altogether and the behavior is the same.

Am I missing something?  Should Spring pass along the POST request after authentication or does that not happen by design for some reason?

Here is my Spring security config:

```
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <form-login 
            login-page="/login.htm" 
            default-target-url="/hello.htm" 
            always-use-default-target="false"
            authentication-failure-url="/login.htm?error" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login.htm?logout" />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
        <user name="admin" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        <user name="super" password="man" authorities="ROLE_SUPER_USER" />
        </user-service>
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Here is my jsp to initiate the test (a link to test the GET and a form to test the POST):

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include.jsp" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<html>
  <head><title>TEST SECURITY</title></head>
  <body>
        <p><a href="admin/security_landing.htm">GET</a></p>
        <form:form  method="POST" action="admin/security_landing.htm"><input type="submit" value="POST"></form:form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the landing page which is a secured resource:

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include.jsp" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<html>
  <head><title>TEST SECURITY LANDING PAGE</title></head>
  <body>
        <p>YOU MADE IT!!!!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is my test controller:

```
package springapp.web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;


@Controller
public class TestController {

    /** Logger for this class and subclasses */
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @RequestMapping(value="test", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView methodGet()
            {

        logger.info("Found it's way to the GET method");

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

        model.setViewName("security_test");

        return model;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/admin/security_landing", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView sendToLandingPOST()
            {

        logger.info("Found it's way to the GET method");

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

        model.setViewName("/admin/security_landing");

        return model;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/admin/security_landing", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView sendToLandingGET()
            {

        logger.info("Found it's way to the GET method");

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

        model.setViewName("/admin/security_landing");

        return model;

    }
}
```

I can include more of the Spring configuration if it's relevant, but where the app is working fine with a GET but misbehaving (in my opinion) with a POST, I'm thinking it's isolated to the pieces I've shown here.

It seems to me that Spring security should be able to intercept a POST and pass along the POST after authentication, just like a GET.

Any hints or help would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Rob

Comment: By way of experimenting I have isolated the issue to the presence of CSRF protection being enabled.  When the <csrf/> tag is present in the security configuration this issue occurs.  When it is removed the application works as expected.  Not sure why yet, but at least I've isolated the cause.

Comment: If you're using CSRF checking, then you need to submit the CSRF token in your form submission. There's an example in [the manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-using).

Comment: Thanks Luke, I'm actually using the Spring form libraries with the form:form tag, which is supposed to handle the CSRF tag automatically, but I've also tried explicitly including the token as well.  No luck.  I found this in the documentation which makes me believe that this behavior might be by design.

Comment: 2.1.12. <csrf>
This element will add Cross Site Request Forger (CSRF) protection to the application. It also updates the default RequestCache to only replay "GET" requests upon successful authentication. Additional information can be found in the Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF)section of the reference.

Comment: That passage can be found here:  http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf

Comment: Hmm. Maybe the CSRF feature is only available after authenticated users. Did you check if the system actually renders a CSRF token in your request form? Rob Winch is probably best placed to answer, since he's the one who implemented the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out, when CSRF is enabled Spring Security will only save GET requests. The reason is that the CSRF token is changed as soon as a user authenticates to prevent a malicious user from finding out the CSRF before a user authenticates (i.e. in a public setting). If we cached the request, then it would be replayed with the old CSRF and fail CSRF validation anyways.

In general, saving a POST request and automatically processing it seems to be a bit dangerous. Consider a situation where a public computer contains access to a commonly used site. A malicious user performs a POST to the unauthenticated application that transfers funds from the currently authenticated user to their bank account. The application caches the POST and then brings up the log in form. The malicious user walks away and a victim sees that the log in page is already present. Furthermore the URL in the browser is correctly displayed and over HTTPS. The victim logs in and the originally requested POST request is replayed and automatically transfers funds from the victim to the malicious user.

Instead, we should probably be ensuring that an intermediate page is displayed when a POST is going to be replayed.