# Spring Security Login returns Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I created a simple Spring mvc application with spring security and hibernate. When i am trying to login it returns the error message `"Request method 'POST' not supported"`.
Here is my web.xml and servelet contexts.

### Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring/springsecurity-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


</web-app>
```

### servletcontext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Configure to plugin JSON as request and response in method handler -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <beans:property name="messageConverters">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
    <beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- 
    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.0.0.25:1433;databaseName=3PLTest;" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="sa" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="sa" />
    </beans:bean>
    -->
    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:sqlserver://SYS-001\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=3PLTest" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="sa" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="sa" />
    </beans:bean>
    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.dimensions.warehouse.model.Employee</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.dimensions.warehouse.model.User</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="employeeDAO" class="com.dimensions.warehouse.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="employeeService" class="com.dimensions.warehouse.service.EmployeeServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="employeeDAO" ref="employeeDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="userDAO" class="com.dimensions.warehouse.dao.UserDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="userService" class="com.dimensions.warehouse.service.UserServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="userDAO" ref="userDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.dimensions.warehouse.service.UserDetailsServiceImp">
        <beans:property name="userDAO" ref="userDAO" ></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dimensions.warehouse" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="*" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="userServicePointCut"
        expression="execution(* com.dimensions.warehouse.service.*Service.*(..))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="userServicePointCut" />
    </aop:config>


</beans:beans>
```

### Springsecurity-servlet.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/employees**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
        <form-login 
            login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/welcome"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService" >
            <password-encoder hash="plaintext" />    
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

### appservlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dimensions.warehouse.*" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Most likely you have the same issue as described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763958/spring-security-3-2-5-http-post-not-forwarding-to-the-original-request-after-a).